# Download PDF in Android using Ionicv4

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using `ionic v4`. I have a `web page` where when completing a `form`, a `PDF file` is downloaded. I want to perform this same action on the `Android device`.
How can I do it using `webview`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information?

You just want do download a specific PDF link file? Maybe something like this:

**Using href**

1. Define a variable with the desired URL link:

```
    var url="https://www.w3schools.com?name=ADAM"
```

2. Insert into your html file:

```
    < a target="_blank" href="{{url}}">PDF< / a>
```

If you share some code I can help you out more...